# angularJS controller method with ng-options

Tags: angularjs, select

I have a scenario where i need to create drop-down dynamically inside ng-repeat and the data source for drop-down is also dynamic, meaning based on the query i need to bind my dropdown.

So, i decdided to call controller method, where i have a http get, by passing the query based on the query my service will return a generic data with key value pair. when i call the controller method i am ending up wih infinte loop

**Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop**

**My Html**

```
 <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><strong>Enter Parameters</strong></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr ng-repeat="x in reportDataParameter.UserParameterList">

                        <td>{{x.UserParamDefinition.DisplayLabel}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <select ng-model="x.Model" ng-options="item.ValueField as item.TextField for item in executeQuery(x.UserParamDefinition.Query)" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.reportDataParameter = {};     

    $scope.reportDataParameter = {
        "UserParameterList": [
            {
                "Key": "StateID",
                "Value": "?ddl,State,State",
                "UserParamDefinition": {
                    "DataType": "ddl",
                    "DisplayLabel": "State",
                    "Model": null,
                    "Query": "SELECT Id AS ValueField, BankName AS TextField FROM BankDetail"
                }
            },
            {
                "Key": "FacilityParentID",
                "Value": "?ddl,FacilityParent,FacilityParent",
                "UserParamDefinition": {
                    "DataType": "ddl",
                    "DisplayLabel": "FacilityParent",
                    "Model": null,
                    "Query": "SELECT Id AS ValueField, Name AS TextField FROM Organization"
                }
            }
        ],
        "ReportTitle": "Facility List By Parent",
        "Description": null,
        "ReportPage": null
    };

 $scope.executeQuery = function (query) {
              var baseUrl = 'https://localhost:62';
        return $http.get(baseUrl + '/api/reports/executequery/' + query).then(function (result) {
            return result.data;
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to simplify your code in the question as much as you can: everything will be clearer to readers, and to you, too... :-) You should also  review your introductory text (second sentence expecially)...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remember that a function that you bind in a template is evaluated every digest cycle. `executeQuery(x.UserParamDefinition.Query)` is called every digest cycle for each `ng-repeat` entry. In your case that is two function calls per cycle.

Furthermore, each call queries the server using `$http` so you query the server every cycle.

Then, you use a promise in your `ng-options` once the promise is resolved a new digest is started and your function is called again. That's why you end up with the infinite loop. Apart from the issue that a promise is not a valid input for `ng-options`. The

The `return result.data;` of your callback just vanishes into thin air as it is not bound by the controller and not returned by `executeQuery` (that returns the promise).

The easiest way to resolve this is to bind your query data to a variable in your `UserParameterList` entries and query the server if the variable is not set. You could use a getter-method for that. Something like this would also be possible:

```
$scope.executeQuery = function(item) {
    var baseUrl = 'https://localhost:62';
    $http.get(baseUrl + '/api/reports/executequery/' + item.UserParamDefinition.Query)
         .then(function (result) {
             item.queryResult = result.data;
         });
}
```

In your template, you just use `x.queryResult`. If `UserParameterList` does not change, you could just run through the array once and execute `executeQuery` for each entry. If it does change, you could use a watcher to track changes an execute `executeQuery`. If `UserParameterList` indeed changes, you need to have concurrency in mind as in "items can change while a query is running" and deal with it.

Comment: Excellent, perfect solution.